# If $a \equiv b \pmod n$ and $c+d = n$, does $ca+bd \equiv 0 \pmod n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am trying to prove a different equation and am able to if the following is true, but I am not exactly sure if it is true.

If $a\equiv b \pmod{9}$ and $c+d = 9$, is $ca+bd \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$ a true statement?

I have tried various examples, like

$a = 29$, $b = 2$, $c = 2$, and $d = 7$

$a = 13$, $b = 4$, $c = 4$, and $d = 5$

and more.

If anyone has a counterexample, please let me know! Otherwise, if this is true, then can someone please explain why? Thanks!

Comment: Use $a=b+9k$ in $ca+bd$

Comment: Hint: eliminate $\,a\,$ & $\,c\,$ and apply congruence sum & product rules - see my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a\equiv b\pmod{9}$ and $c+d=9$ implies $a-b\equiv 0\pmod{9}$ and $d\equiv -c \pmod{9}$ ,respectively. So

$$ca+bd\equiv ca-cb\equiv c(a-b)\equiv c\cdot 0\equiv 0 \pmod{9}.$$

Answer (score 6):

If $a\equiv b\pmod n$, then this is just
$$a(c+d) \equiv an\equiv 0\pmod n$$

Answer (score 4):

$$ \begin{align}&\ \ \ \ \ \color{#c00}a\ \equiv\,\ \color{#c00}b\\ &\ \ \ \ \ \color{#0a0}c\ \equiv \color{#0a0}{-d}_{\phantom{|}}\\ \hline 
{\Longrightarrow}\ \ &\ \ \  \color{#0a0}c\ \color{#c00}a\,+\,d\,b\\[.2em] 
{\equiv}\ \ \ & \color{#0a0}{-d}\,\color{#c00}b\,+\,d\,b\,\equiv\, 0\end{align}\qquad$$

Comment: We *eliminated* $\,a\,$ & $\,c\,$ using the [Congruence Sum & Product Rules](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\ \ $

Comment: Do you manually insert the code like `\color{#c00}` when needed or do you have a tool for coloring conveniently?

Comment: @Jack  Sometimes I use tools (AHK,Emacs,etc) sometimes by hand (depends on the device).

Answer (score 2):

Just to list another approach:
$$
ac+bd = a\underbrace{(c+d)}_{\text{multiple of $9$}} + \underbrace{(b-a)}_{\text{multiple of $9$}}d,
$$
(this is an equal sign, not a congruent sign) 
so the left-hand side must be a multiple of $9$, too.